# Compare the date in a column to headers of other columns and generate a dummy based on the comparison in Python

Tags: python

I have a data frame containing 10 columns. The first column contains some dates. The headers for the other 9 columns are some other dates. The values for these 9 columns are pre-set to zero.

I would like to compare the value of the date in the first column to each of the headers of the other 9 columns and change the value from 0 to 1 if a certain condition is met. for example, if the date in the first column is within the 5-year period prior to each header date, change the value from 0 to 1. An example follows:

starting dataframe:

| date | 04-Feb-94 | 31-Jan-96 | 19-Aug-97 | 18-Apr-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/26/90 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/08/95 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 03/10/98 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

desired output:

| date | 04-Feb-94 | 31-Jan-96 | 19-Aug-97 | 18-Apr-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/26/90 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/08/95 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 03/10/98 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's do this!

**1.** First you'll need to convert "column names" (*header*) to date format (*alias timestamp*) like this:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:]).tolist()
```

**1.1** Then you'll have to convert the column "date" to date format too:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

**2.** Now we can do the 12th comparisons (*columns 4*3 rows*) with a for loop while updating cell value accordingly when we match our condition:

```
for i in df.columns[1:]:
  for j in range(len(df.date)):
    if df.date[j] < i < (df.date[j] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=5)):
      df.at[j, i] = 1
```

**3.** Output:

| index | date | 1994-02-04 00:00:00 | 1996-01-31 00:00:00 | 1997-08-19 00:00:00 | 2001-04-18 00:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1990-07-26 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1995-05-08 00:00:00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1998-03-10 00:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you, While I was waiting for an answer I came up with an approach that was similar to yours, nonethless, I learned from your code. Best :)